# Add marker to google map from JSON in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, google-maps, gps

I was trying to add markers to a google map after getting the data from online JSON. The JSON file update each 50sec and I use a timer to read that file repetitively. My codes are shown below. After the program is executed, the program closes. For details see the source code attached

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it is right but there's a mistake in your code.

```
private void SetPoint(String Latitude, String Altitude, String Time) {
    point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(**Latitude**), 
    Double.parseDouble(**Altitude**));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(Time));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
}
```

Comment: I do it, but the program is still closed after the run

Comment: Closed after the run means? You mean a crash?

Comment: Yes I have a crash. After the map load and  ProgressDialog show, the proogram close

Comment: @RezaDehghani could you please post the error/exception that occurred?

Comment: @AM the error that show after crash is:
could not get json from server. check logcat for possible errors

Comment: Please check if your web service is responding. Try opening it in a browser

Answer (score 0):

Try with following changes you are passing same values to `latitude` and `longitude`

```
SetPoint(pointList.get(i).get("lat").toString(), pointList.get(i).get("lng").toString(), pointList.get(i).get("time").toString());

//----------Set Point--------------------

private void SetPoint(String Latitude, String Altitude, String Time) {

    point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Latitude), Double.parseDouble(Altitude));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(Time));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

}
```